# Azure Function EventGrid Trigger does not support Key Vault references?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-eventgrid

Originally this Function was triggered by `BlobStorage` uploads. I changed the Function to now be triggered by `EventGridEvents`.

I'm now trying to register an event, but the trigger still shows `Azure Blob Storage (myblob)` as the trigger.

I've published the app 2x and refreshed a couple times, no avail.

Ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how I fixed this:**

- Went into Portal and clicked `Code+Test`, `Test/Run` then `Run`

[image]

- This resulted in errors which said the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value was incorrect.
- I was using a Key Vault *reference* in `local.settings.json` rather than a Connection String directly (to keep secrets out of my code)
- In `local.settings.json`, changed from the Key Vault Reference to the actual Connection String.
- Re-published
- Refreshed a couple times
- Then...

Trigger shows correctly

[image]

- Reverted to Key Vault **Reference** in `local.settings.json` and republished to test if errors return.
- **Sure enough:**

```
2020-10-05T23:37:11.138 [Information] Initializing Warmup Extension./home/LogFiles/Application/Functions/Host/2020-10-05T21-04-07Z-59062a025e.log  (https://function-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/Application/Functions/Host/2020-10-05T21-04-07Z-59062a025e.log)
2020-10-05T21:04:07.832 [Information] Host started (642ms)
2020-10-05T21:04:07.833 [Information] Job host started
2020-10-05T21:04:07.835 [Error] The 'function-dev' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.function-dev'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string for 'AzureWebJobsStorage' is invalid.
```

Looks like using Key Vault **References** as AppSettings is unsupported with EventGrid triggers(?).

Comment: I have the same problem and yes, looks like keyvault references in local.settings.json like this:

"AzureWebJobsStorage": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://.....)"

is not supported.